# Sequelize update looks at wrong column in where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to make an update function in sequelize but it is looking at the wrong column in the query. this is the function

```
    return StudentAssignment.findOne({
      where: { id: req.params.id }
    })
      .then(studentAssignment => {
        if (!studentAssignment) {
          return res
            .status(404)
            .send({ message: "StudentAssignment not found" });
        }
        return studentAssignment
          .update(
            {
              assignmentStatus: studentAssignment.assignmentStatus + 1
            },
            {
              where: { id: studentAssignment.id }
            }
          )
          .then(res.status(200).send(studentAssignment))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
```

but this is the query it is executing:
[image]

It is looking at studentAssignment.assingmentId and not studentAssignment.id
Can you help me please?

Comment: Pretty strange and cannot replicate this. Are you sure the about generated SQL statement related to this update statement?

Comment: I am sure that the statement relates to update. Another weird thing is that findById() also looks at the assignmentId which is why i have to use findOne().

Comment: Please share your schema definition